# Variables in a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select the last cell (last row, last column).

```
Range(ColumnName & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
```

ColumnName is the last column alphabetical (e.g: D) declared like a String.

This doesn't work. But this yes:

```
Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
```

EDIT:

```
'colNum as integer (e.g: 4)
'this code transform number to alphabetical

Public Function ColumnName(colNum As Integer) As String
Dim d As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim name As String
d = colNum
name = ""
Do While (d > 0)
    m = (d - 1) Mod 26
    name = Chr(65 + m) + name
    d = Int((d - m) / 26)
Loop
ColumnName = name
'If i do     "MsgBox ColumnName", and "MsgBox CStr(Len(ColumnName))" I obtain D, and 1.
End Function
```

Comment: where is your declaration of a string

Comment: My guess is that the formula you are using to find the last column is returning the results in numerical R1C1 style which is why when parsing through the range function you are getting an error. my solution below should solve your problem.

Comment: Instead of `Range(ColumnName & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select` you should try `Cells(Rows.Count,ColumnName).end(xlUp).select` alternative solution posted below. FYI you wouldnt even need to convert your column Number to Column name and save multiple lines of code

Comment: Thanks!
You have helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to declare ColumnName as a variable.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ColumnName As String
    ColumnName = "D"
    Range(ColumnName & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
End Sub
```

Here is a more popular way to do it.

```
Sub SelectLastCellInColumnOption()
    Dim Rws As Long
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(Rws, "D").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I edit the post with more information. I tried your code , but I don't know why doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There should be *no* difference between `"D"` and a string variable with the value `"D"`, hence I would suggest that perhaps your contention that `ColumnName` is `"D"` may be incorrect. Please check this thoroughly.

You can do so with something like:

```
MsgBox ColumnName
MsgBox CStr(Len(ColumnName))
```

and make sure you get `D` and `1` as the result.

Answer (score 0):

To find the last Cell you can try this. This is not exactly an amendment of your Code but the below result will help you SELECT the Last Cell in the current sheet which If I  understand correctly from the first sentence is your ask.

```
Dim LCol As Long
LCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
Cells(Rows.Count, LCol).End(xlUp).Select
```